# SDL GFX shrinkSurface issues

Tags: c++, image, sdl

I am looking for anyone who has experience in using SDL and its GFX system. I am trying to write a simple piece of code to shrink an surface and figured SDL's GFX system would speed things up, but I continually get "undefined reference to shrinkSuface" I have included the "SDL_rotozoom.h," and know that it is recognizes shrinkSurface as a function, but no matter what I have tried I have only gotten errors. I have tried to look in the documentation and the actual C files, but have not been able to find the issue. Probably something simple I am overlooking. I would appreciate any input on the matter though.

```
 SDL_Surface* CSurface::Shrink(SDL_Surface* Surf_Src, int X , int Y)
{
    if(Surf_Src == 0){
        return false;
    }

    return shrinkSurface(Surf_Src , X , Y);
}
```

Also if it helps anyone out, the link to the documentation is [here](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/_s_d_l__rotozoom_8c.html#aad3bf0cd89cc39ff874ffa778fa1495d) at close to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Are you taking into account that the X and Y parameters are factors, not absolute sizes?  I.e. if you have a 100x100 pixel surface, and you call `shrinkSurfacer( surf, 50, 50 )`, it won't scale to 50x50 pixels, but actually (1/50)*100 x (1/50)*100 (so 2x2 pixels)

Comment: Yes, I am factoring it progressively over a loop and stopping the loop before progressing out of bounds.

Comment: is it possible you're scaling down to the point that X or Y become zero?

Comment: No there is an if statement that returns before scaling reaches 50%, I have double checked that just to make sure everything is working as it should.